# Replacing certain character in email addresses with '*' in an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

From example@gmail.com

```
exam***@gm***.com
```

Can anyone mask the email using SQL query.AS show above from `example@gmail.com` and convert it to

```
exam***@gm***.com
```

Comment: what is the logic behind ?like abcde@mno.au=?

Comment: @KumarHarsh I need this in SQL SELECT QUERY FROM TABLE . Actually  i want to mask email address  with * first 4 letter will be shown and after @ 2 letter will be shown rest of will be *.

Comment: just out of curiosity whats the use of removing gmail and making it gm****.com,

Comment: just trying like Gmail Recovery Password example which is my college project base after user forget his password he can recover it using email and the email should be show as explain above

Comment: If your email address is `bob@gmail.com` presenting it as `bob@gm***.com` hardly obfuscates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'example@gmail.com'

SELECT  LEFT(@String, 3) + '*****@' 
        + REVERSE(LEFT(RIGHT(REVERSE(@String) , CHARINDEX('@', @String) +2), 2))
        + '******'
        + RIGHT(@String, 4)
```

**Result**

```
exa*****@gm******.com
```

Just thought of another simpler solution

```
SELECT LEFT(@String, 3) + '*****@' 
       + SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX('@',@String)+1,2)
       + '*******'
       + RIGHT(@String, 4)
```

This will also give you the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

while insert you can do same from c# code.
try this with other example,

```
Declare @input varchar(50)='example@gmail.com '

select left(@input,4)+replicate('*',len(substring(@input,5,charindex('@',@input)-5)))
+substring(@input,charindex('@',@input),3)
+replicate('*',len(substring(@input,charindex('@',@input)+3,len(@input)-charindex('.',@input))))
+substring(@input,charindex('.',@input),len(@input))
```

Answer (score 0):

may be a multi replace works, an alternative masking the vocals:

```
update table set mail = replace(replace(mail,'a','*') ,'e','*') and go on
```